# Creating Dataset for Image Classification

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I want to develop a CNN model to identify 24 hand signs in American Sign Language. I created a custom [dataset](http://www.kaggle.com/dataset/04322e12909662a11f5154857a749b54b389b77bd99f5bd4c3e0db0ec34abe68) that contains 3000 images for each hand sign i.e. 72000 images in the entire dataset.

For training the model, I would be using 80-20 dataset split (2400 images/hand sign in the training set and 600 images/hand sign in the validation set). My question is:
Should I randomly shuffle the images when creating the dataset? And Why?

PS: Based on my previous experience, it led to validation loss being lower than training loss and validation accuracy more than training accuracy.

Comment: The answer is: Yes, you should shuffle the dataset, for an explanation check think [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24511/why-should-the-data-be-shuffled-for-machine-learning-tasks). About the higher validation/training loss: is a consistent over several training trials? Also, is it consistent over several epochs or does it happened only at the beginning of each training?

Comment: The validation loss was low throughout the training phase. You can check it here= https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/18551/validation-loss-is-lower-than-training-loss

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero That looks a lot like an answer rather than a comment. Please consider expanding it to an answer, and adding a little extra detail about what's in the link.